# Is this the correct way of doing bubble sort?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

just wondering whether this is the correct way of doing a Bubble Sort algorithm. I found this in the internet the way of doing Bubble sort but I didn't get the logic of this algorithm, this is the algorithm from a website:

```
    int n = arr.length;  
    int temp = 0;  
     for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
           {  
             for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++)
                 {  
                      if(arr[j-1] > arr[j])
                        {  
                             //swap elements  
                             temp = arr[j-1];  
                             arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                             arr[j] = temp;  
                        }  

             }
```

I understand that you need nested loops in Bubblesort however the part I don't understand is why you need

```
for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
    if(arr[j-1] > arr[j])
```

Why is "n minus 1" needed or "j minus 1 needed", can't you just have two exact for loops like  `for(int i=0; i < n; i++)` and  `for(int j=0; j < n; j++)`
as a nested loop? Can anybody give me a visual layman's term explanation why this is.

Hence I have produced a Bubble sort Algorithm with two exact same nested loops.
But I don't know whether it is alright. Here is the code:

```
   import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
   import java.util.Arrays;

   // one class needs to have a main() method
   public class HelloWorld
   {
     // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {


         int integerArray [] = {4,6,1,3,2,8,678,122,12,29,57, -1};
     int temporaryValue;


     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)  // integerArray.lenght
     {
       for(int j = 0; j<11; j++)
       {
         if (integerArray [j] > integerArray [j+1])
             {temporaryValue = integerArray[j];
              integerArray [j] = integerArray [j+1];
              integerArray [j+1] = temporaryValue;
             }
       }
     }



   for (int j = 0; j < integerArray.length; j++)
     {
       System.out.print(integerArray[j]+",");


     }

 }
}
```

Comment: Bubble sort guarantees placement of one item at the end of the structure, so you don't need to re-examine it.

Comment: If the site where you found the code doesn't explain how it works, or why it does what it does, then I suggest you don't use the code. Find a book or tutorial which explains it more in detail, and try to implement it yourself rather than just copy someone elses code which you don't understand.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is this correct?” an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359466/why-is-is-this-correct-an-off-topic-question-and-what-should-i-ask-instead)

Comment: To "Some programmer dude", yes that is what I did, I implemented the code basically on my own, which is the second part

Answer (score 0):

You need (n -i) because after each pass, you know that the greatest element is at its right position[end]. So, you don't need to perform any swap operation for this greatest element.It just reduces the number of swap operations.

You don't need (j -1). The example iterates j from index 1 to (n - i)[excluded] and you are iterating j from index 0 to (integerArray.length - 1)[excluded]

Suggestion: Take a pen and paper and execute your algorithm. You will be able to understand why we need (n -i)